# Primefaces :Accessing rows of a datatable programmatically

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I need to iterate over all the row data programmatically. Once I have the org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable object, I can get the content of the current row using #getRowData(). #getColumns().getChildren() returns a List which has only one UiComponent, that too of row 1.

What is the correct way of iterating through the row datas?

**Solved**
Using dataTable.setRowIndex(rowIndex), one can fetch columns from a particular row.

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {
    table.setRowIndex(rowIndex);
    columns = table.getColumns();
    // Your Code Goes Here
}
```

Comment: ok close the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved** Using dataTable.setRowIndex(rowIndex), one can fetch columns from a particular row.

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {
    table.setRowIndex(rowIndex);
    columns = table.getColumns();
    // Your Code Goes Here
}
```